# Determining if a variable is from a list of several values in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to figure out an easier way to determine if a variable is one of several values in Lua. In this case, I'm trying to check if variable  `Player.Name` is equal to `"Player1"`, `"Player2"` or `"Player3"` (example names), and then change the variable `image.Image`:

This code works:

```
        if Player.Name == "Player1" or Player.Name == "Player2" or Player.Name == "Player3" then
            image.Image = "rbxassetid://4743025782"
        else
            image.Image = "rbxassetid://0"
        end
```

but I hate doing this for every `Player.Name` I have to add, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: I can't see a reason why anyone would hate Lua

Comment: please note that the accepted answer doesn't save you any time with increasing number of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a lookup table also known as `set`.

```lua
local AllowedPlayerNames = {
    Player1 = true,
    Player2 = true,
    Player3 = true
}

if AllowedPlayerNames[Player.Name] then -- If `Player.Name` is in AllowedPlayerNames it returns its value, which is `true`.
    image.Image = "rbxassetid://4743025782"
else
    image.Image = "rbxassetid://0"
end
```

lookup table is a regular table but the keys are the accepted values and value can be any value, we need truthy value to make if statement to work, so `true` is fine.

Note: You can write string keys as variables if they follow Lua's [naming conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1)

> Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of Latin
> letters, Arabic-Indic digits, and underscores, not beginning with a
> digit and not being a reserved word. Identifiers are used to name
> variables, table fields, and labels.

If you have different type or string with other characters use this syntax:

`["Player1"] = true` (this is the same as `Player1 = true`)

Comment: if you're using a Lookup table why not use the image string or at least an index for a image map for each player? that way you save the conditional statement.

Comment: @Piglet His example didn't have different images for different person, that wasn't in the question.

Comment: I don't think implying that someone who's giving you a friendly advice, is unable to read a simple question is very nice. adding more image names is a forseeable future need that can be dealt with right from the start without any additional efforts. that's all I'm saying.  I fixed your explainations on string keys as they were incomplete and difficult to understand for a beginner. again no offense intended

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookup table that defines an image for particular names and defaults to another image if the name is not listed

```
local playerImages = setmetatable({
    ["Han Solo"] = "rbxassetid://4743025782",
    ["Luke Skywalker"] = "rbxassetid://4743025782",
  }, {
     __index = function() return "rbxassetid://0" end})

local playerName1 = "Han Solo"
local playerName2 = "Mickey Mouse"
print(playerImages[playerName1])
print(playerImages[playerName2])
```

Or if the player image is player specific, simply make it a propety of each player and use something like `Player.Image` wherever you need it.

Alternatively create a list of image strings:

```
local images = {
  [1] = "image1",
  [2] = "image2",
  default = "defaultImage"}

local playerImg = {
  ["Player1"] = 1,
  ["Player2"] = 2,
}

local imgIndex = playerImg[PlayerName]
local img = playerImg[imgIndex] or playerImg.default
```